# Splash screen for Android tab bar application

Tags: android, android-webview, splash-screen

I have created the android application with tabhost. In this application, I am having the 4 tabs and each one contains their separate webview. For this application, I want to add SplashScreen for the application before the tab bar's webview is loaded. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a different activity to show the splash which will be your launcher activity. After launching you can start the tabhost from this activity

Comment: I am using the following code to create the tab bar in the mainactivity.  addTabBar(this); 
     addTabItem("file:///android_asset/WebApplication/GetContacts.html", "View1", null);    
   
     addTabItem("file:///android_asset/WebApplication/AddContact.html", "View2", null);      
   
     addTabItem("file:///android_asset/WebApplication/GetContacts.html", "View4", null);                     These methods are used for creating the Tab bar and loading the webview. In this way of creating the webview how can I add the splash screen?

Comment: If I am showing and hiding the splash screen in onPageStarted() and onPageFinished() method, the splash screen is loaded inside the first tab webview

Comment: Is any sugesstion for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    // time for splashscreen
    protected int _splashTime = 5000;

    private Thread splashTread;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        final SplashScreen sPlashScreen = this;

        // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
        splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {

                        // wait 5 sec
                        wait(_splashTime);
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                } finally {


                    // Go to Main activity
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(sPlashScreen, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();


                }
            }
        };

        splashTread.start();
    }


}
```

Hope it helps.